# no such file or directory error when using variables (works otherwise)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am new to programming and just starting in bash.
I'm trying to print a list of directories and files to a txt file, and remove some of the path that gets printed to make it cleaner. 
 It works with this:

```
TODAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
cd
cd Downloads
ls -R ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music | sed 's/\/Users\/BilPaLo\/Music\/iTunes\/iTunes\ Media\/Music\///g' > music-list-$TODAY.txt
```

But to clean it up I want to use variables like so,

```
# Creates a string of the date, format YYYY-MM-DD
TODAY="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"

# Where my music folders are
MUSIC="$HOME/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/"

# Where I want it to go
DESTINATION="$HOME/Downloads/music-list-"$TODAY".txt"

# Path name to be removed from text file
REMOVED="\/Users\/BilPaLo\/Music\/iTunes\/iTunes\ Media\/Music\/"

ls -R "$MUSIC" > "$DESTINATION"
sed "s/$REMOVED//g" > "$DESTINATION"
```

but it gives me a 'no such file or directory' error that I can't seem to get around.
I'm sure there are many other problems with this code but this one I don't understand.

Comment: Add a filename to your last `sed` command.

Comment: `bash -x yourscript` is your friend. Compare the logs it generates from the broken and working versions of the script, and you'll see the problem.

Comment: And btw, don't use `s/foo/bar/` when your `foo` or `bar` values contain slashes -- just pick a different sigil: `s@foo@bar@` lets you have slashes inside `foo` and `bar` without any need for escaping.

Comment: BTW, the backslash in `MUSIC="$HOME/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/"` is wrong. The quotes escape the space; you don't need an additional backslash.

Comment: (and as another aside -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or system; your scripts should use lowercase names for their own variables to avoid unintentional conflicts; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Comment: (Consider fixing everything found by http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here)

Comment: Thank you all ! This helped a lot - I posted my now working and cleaned up code in an answer below

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone! I followed the much needed formatting advice and @amo-ej1's answer and now this works:

```
# Creates a string of the date format YYYY-MM-DD
today="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"

# Where my music folders are
music="$HOME/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/"

# Where I want it to go
destination="$HOME/Downloads/music-list-$today.txt"

# Temporary file
temp="$HOME/Downloads/temp.txt"

# Path name to be removed of text file to only leave artist name and album
remove="\\/Users\\/BilPaLo\\/Music\\/iTunes\\/iTunes\\ Media\\/Music\\/"

# lists all children of music and writes it in temp
ls -R "$music" > "$temp" 
# substitutes remove by nothing and writes it in destination
sed "s/$remove//g" "$temp" > "$destination" 

rm $temp #deletes temp
```

Answer (score 0):

First when debugging bash it can be helpful to start bash with the *-x* flags (`bash -x script.sh`) or within the script enter `set -x`, that way bash will print out the commands it is executing (with the variable expansions) and you can more easily spot errors that way.

In this specific snippet our ls output is being redirected to a file called `$DESTINATION` and and sed will read from standard input and write also to `$DESTINATION`. So however you wanted to replace the pipe in your oneliner is wrong. As a result this will look as if your program is blocked but sed will simply wait for input arriving on standard input.

As for the 'no such file or directory', try executing with `set -x` and doublecheck the paths it is trying to access.